# Client Side PGP Encryption of File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, encryption

Basically I have a form, and I am using ajax to perform some operations on the data client side (such as encryption).

I also need to handle a file upload though.

How do I upload file contents as a string into Javascript?

Then I can encrypt them client side with a public key and AJAX post them to my server.

Didn't post code, because I don't have any for this, as I don't even know if it is possible.

Hopefully you guys can shed some light.

TLDR; Can file contents be uploaded as variable into JavaScript (must be completely client side).

Comment: If you are doing your AJAX post via SSL this would be handled for you I believe - automatically. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No, SSL is not enough for me, I am already using SSL but the problem is that I want to have a full proof end to end system. Even the server should not ever see plain text.

Comment: Do you want to be able to unencrypt it at all?

Comment: Yes, the beholder of the private key associated with the public key used to encrypt the file will be able to then decrypt the file client side.

Comment: There's a good reason why I don't think this is possible, but I guess we will have to see what more people have to say.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for the following: https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt along with http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ to read files from a local PC - I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem isn't about the PGP encryption, but rather whether or not it is possible to upload local file contents as a string variable into JavaScript.

Comment: Lets say I have a file in my desktop, can I read the bytes as a string into a variable in javascript? Similar to file_get_contents(); in php

Comment: Hey, I got an update, and it's definitely possible to do this. I can already to file reading and such, but here is the thing. How do I do the following? Lets say I read the file as ArrayBuffer to the var ab. I then convert ab to Uint8Array... How do I convert Uint8Array back to arraybuffer?